# The stalk of a specialization is a localization of the generization.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

So I am trying to prove that in for a scheme locally of finite type over an algebraically closed field, smoothness and regularity are the same thing. I am working in Görtz and Wedhorn. In lemma 6.26, one direction of this fact is shown. The first part of the proof states that we can restrict to closed points because if $x'\in \overline{\{x\}}$ is a closed point then $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ is a localization of $\mathcal O_{X, x'}$ and so if the stalk at $x'$ is regular so is the stalk at $x$.

This is stated without any explanation so it might be an elementary fact but I cannot seem to figure it out. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean the other way around, ie $x'\in \overline{\{x\}}$ ?

Comment: You're right, I edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose an affine open neighborhood of $x'$ (which then necessarily contains $x$). Then we may assume that $X=Spec(R)$, and $x$ and $x'$ correspond respectively to prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ in $R$, such that $\mathfrak{p}\subset \mathfrak{q}$.

Then $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=R_\mathfrak{p} = (R_\mathfrak{q})_{\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{q}} = (\mathcal{O}_{X,x'})_{\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_{X,x'}}$, because in general, if $S\subset T$ are multiplicative sets in a ring $R$, then $T^{-1}R = (S^{-1}T)^{-1}(S^{-1}R)$ (the notation is a little heavy, but it just means that to invert all the elements of $T$ you may start by inverting the elements of $S$ and then invert the image of $T$ in that).

Comment: Why does an affine neighborhood of $x'$ need to contain $x$?

Comment: Because $x'\in \overline{\{x\}}$ precisely means that $x$ is in every neighborhood of $x'$ (this is true in any topological space, nothing special about schemes here).

Comment: Ah yes of course. Thank you very much!